# how to resque Log4j output from html tag

Tags: log4j

I have log4j files, but it writes into console with html tags like  like this.
Is there any solution or another offering for good and readable output for log4j output.

log4j setting is like;

```
<appender name="STDOUT" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{2} - %m%n"/>
        </layout>       
    </appender>
```

My output is like that

```
<tr>
<th>Time</th>
<th>Thread</th>
<th>Level</th>
<th>Category</th>
<th>Message</th>
</tr>
</table>
<br>
</body></html><!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title>HTML Layout Example</title>
<style type="text/css">
<!--
body, table {font-family: arial,sans-serif; font-size: x-small;}
th {background: #336699; color: #FFFFFF; text-align: left;}
-->
</style>
</head>
<body bgcolor="#FFFFFF" topmargin="6" leftmargin="6">
<hr size="1" noshade>
Log session start time Wed Jan 27 16:00:28 EET 2016<br>
<br>
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="4" border="1" bordercolor="#224466" width="100%">
<tr>
<th>Time</th>
<th>Thread</th>
<th>Level</th>
<th>Category</th>
<th>Message</th>
</tr>
```

Comment: Maybe repost, adding your console output?

Answer (score 0):

The small XML fragment above isn't your log4j setup. If it were, your output would look quite different.

This means that you have another (or several) log4j configuration files on the classpath.

To find them, you can use a small unit tests which calls `getClass().getClassLoader().getResources("log4j.xml")`. That gives you an enumeration of URLs which you can iterate over and print. The URLs will tell you all the JARs and projects which contain log4j config files. The first one will be the one which log4j uses.

Running your application with `-Dlog4j.debug=true` can also help.